# Can I make VSTS URL accessible only within my office network?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS to host my source code and a private agent(on-prem) to build it.
Can I make `https://******.visualstudio.com` this URL private so that it is only accessible within my office network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if your account is backed by Azure AD. You can [enable conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/manage-conditional-access) in the Azure portal. This will allow you to block access outside of a specified range of trusted IP addresses.

Comment: Though this will not block Personal Access Tokens and authenticated sessions that are kept alive (or intercepted) are allowed to leave the network.